# Boost Geometry RTree poor query performance under MSVS 2013/2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, random, boost-geometry

I am trying to run the following piece of code in Visual C++ 2013 and 2015. But the performance for query is no good. It takes about 3,000 seconds to finish 1 million searches. I compile the same piece of code in Clang under OS X 10.10 and g++ on under ubuntu 15.04. The query part only takes less than 0.3 second under os x or linux. The difference is about 10,000 times. Something is not right. Any idea is greatly appreciated!

The compiler options I used for VS is as follows:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\ConsoleApplication1.pch"
```

Below is the code:

```
// TestSpatialIndex.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/distance.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    using Point = bg::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
    using Box = bg::model::box<Point>;
    using Value = std::pair<Point, int>;
    using RTree = bgi::rtree<Value, bgi::rstar<8>>;

    std::vector<Value> vv;
    std::vector<Box> vb;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        auto x = (rand() % 360000000) / 1000000.0 - 180;
        auto y = (rand() % 180000000) / 1000000.0 - 90;
        vv.push_back(std::make_pair(Point(x, y), i));
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        auto x = (rand() % 360000000) / 1000000.0 - 180;
        auto y = (rand() % 180000000) / 1000000.0 - 90;
        vb.push_back(Box(Point(x, y), Point(x + 0.005, y + 0.005)));
    }
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    RTree rt2(vv.begin(), vv.end());

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    elapsed_seconds = end - start;

    std::cout << "finished rt2 computation in "
        << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (auto &it : vb) {
        std::vector<Value> v_res;
        rt2.query(bgi::intersects(it), std::back_inserter(v_res));
    }
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed_seconds = end - start;

    std::cout << "finished rt2 query in "
        << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** 
I found statements like `auto x = (rand() % 360000000) / 1000000.0 - 180;` are the culprits. The original purpose was to return latitude and longitude coordinates with 6 decimal places. But RAND_MAX in MSVC is 32767, so `(rand() % 360000000) / 1000000.0` is `equivalent to rand()/1000000.0` which returns a value ranging from 1e-6 to 0.032767. Therefore a 0.005x0.005 region encloses a lot of points. On the other hand in clang and gcc RAND_MAX is 2147483647, which is the largest signed integer representable in 32 bits. The above code will generate uniformly distributed latitude and longitude pairs under clang and gcc. Hence the number of points returned from a intersection query in MSVC is way much more than that from clang or gcc. And that's why it is 10k times slower in MSVC. In VC, I changed `(rand() % 360000000) / 1000000.0` to `(rand() % 36000) / 100.0` and `(rand() % 180000000) / 1000000.0` to `(rand() % 18000) / 100.0`, the performance is now comparable.

Comment: I was going to run this in my VS2013, but could you provide a complete, executable example? I'm not very familiar with those libraries and it's clear that there's a lot you omitted. At a minimum I can let you know if it's something with your compiler settings or computer by running it too.

Comment: Thanks for updating! I just pasted this into VS2013 Community Edition, compiled in release mode, and it performed the computation in 0.28 seconds, but I cut off the querying after a couple of minutes (gotta sleep!). I'll try it in GCC sometime tomorrow if no one gets back to you. One thought, is it possible that gcc and clang optimize out the actual query because it's not used and doesn't affect anything? I suspect not, but 0.3 seconds is how long the initial computation takes...should the query take longer than nearly instant?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to run my code. My apologies for the incomplete code. It was my first question and I messed up the code by deleting variable declarations. I found the problem and updated my post. To answer your question whether v_res is optimized away, I added a variable to accumlate the number of returned points, and print the value just before `return 0`. There is no significant impact to the performance. And the total number of returned points is only a few hundreds. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: It's great that you've found the issue. Instead of `rand()` you could use C++11 pseudo-random number generation or Boost.Random. See also https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful